# How to make cron job to run every 15 minutes on Thursday starting at 4pm?

Tags: cron

What would be the line in crontab to run some script every 15 minutes starting at 4pm every Thursday, until the midnight? How to modify it to run until Friday 11am?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do what you need on a single line, even just the Thursday piece, because you require the last execution to happen at midnight (which is technically Friday). Here are the 2 lines that would do all you described:

*/15 16-23 * * 4 command

*/15 0-11 * * 5 command

First line is for the Thursday piece, which will run every 15 mins from 4 PM to 11:45 PM.
The second line runs on Friday's from midnight until 11 AM, also every 15 mins.